# Contextmenu event is not triggered on iOS 13.1 and above Browser while selecting text

Tags: javascript, ios

The iOS version is updated to 13.1, on the long-press context menu event is not triggering in the browser and it is displaying the default browser context menu.  We want to hide these context menus .

```html
!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
div {
  background: yellow;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>



<div id="myDIV">
<p>Right-click inside this box to see the context menu!


</div>



<script>
document.getElementById("myDIV").addEventListener("contextmenu", myFunction);

function myFunction() {
 alert('context menu fired');

}
</script>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you saying this was working before updating the iOS version and now isn't working? If so, which version was it working on? Have you tried it in a different browser on the same device? One observation is that to make the HTML well-formed, you need a closing `</p>` at the end of the text in `myDIV`. This may or not be the cause of the problem, as browsers generally try to work out the intent event when the HTML isn't well-formed, but well-formed HTML generally leads to more reliable results.